# Bootstrap Theme $variables

Tags: theming

I've made a sub-theme of the Bootstrap theme; however, I am having trouble understanding where `$variables` comes from in the *page.vars.php* file. I made a little "debug" code to print out the variables - unfortunately, the output is exceptionally large and has some strange outputs. I have edited *page.vars.php* using the variables already retrieved from the `$variables` associative array, e.g. I edited the size of the main content section on the page:

```
 $variables['content_column_class'] = ' class="col-md-8 col-sm-6"';
```

This suggests there should be a `'content-column-class'` in the `$variables` array; however, amazingly when I perform `print_r($variables)` it turns out there is none! Furthermore, every variable I have checked that is being accessed in `page.vars.php` seemingly does not exist.

I'd like to edit the `class` of the `primary` / `sidebar_first` sections; however, currently I cannot do this as I don't know how to access them from the `$variables` array.

In sum, *why does* `print_r` *not output the expected?* And, *how do I find out what variables are actually in* `$variables`*?*

Comment: did you rebuild theme registery?

Comment: I'm guessing no (not a clue what you mean). I'll look into it!

Comment: clear cache it will rebuild your theme registory

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to add a new variables in a class is to use `hook_preprocess_page(&$vars)` you can add the classes like the following:

```
$classes = array(
    'classes_main_page' => '',
    'classes_sidebar_first' => '',
    'classes_sidebar_second' => '',
  );

  // Classes when no sidebar
  if(empty($vars['page']['sidebar_first']) && empty($vars['page']['sidebar_second'])) {
    $classes['classes_main_page'] = 'small-12 medium-12 large-12';
  }
// Classes when left and right sidebars
  if(!empty($vars['page']['sidebar_first']) && !empty($vars['page']['sidebar_second'])) {
    $classes['classes_main_page'] = 'small-12 medium-6 large-6 columns';
    $classes['classes_sidebar_first'] = 'small-12 medium-3 large-3 columns';
    $classes['classes_sidebar_second'] = 'small-12 medium-3 large-3 columns';
  }

  // Classes when only left sidebar
  if(!empty($vars['page']['sidebar_first']) && empty($vars['page']['sidebar_second'])) {
    $classes['classes_main_page'] = 'small-12 medium-9 large-9 columns';
    $classes['classes_sidebar_first'] = 'small-12 medium-3 large-3 columns';
  }

  // Classes when only right sidebar
  if(empty($vars['page']['sidebar_first']) && !empty($vars['page']['sidebar_second'])) {
    $classes['classes_main_page'] = 'small-12 medium-9 large-9 columns';
    $classes['classes_sidebar_second'] = 'small-12 medium-3 large-3 columns';
  }
$vars = array_merge($vars, $classes);
```

and then in your page.tpl.php print something like this:

Don't forget to clear cache afterwards

```
<aside class="<?php print $classes_sidebar_second; ?>"> for sidebars
<aside class="<?php print $classes_sidebar_second; ?>"> for main container
```

Thanks

Comment: Ok. But how do you know what the items in the array are? Without knowing the names I can't correctly add classes to the elements.

Comment: use in your tpl file  <aside class="<?php print $classes_sidebar_second; ?>">

Comment: added explanation to the answer. hope it will help now